# MySQL "AND" / "OR" queries on condition

Tags: mysql

I need a way to change the query criteria based on a `IF` condition.

I store service availability hours in a table, so for example if the service is available from "08" to "16", I store those values as `work_start` and `work_end`. I need to check if the service is available currently, and query like this:

`where $current_time > work_start AND $current_type < work_end`.

But for the case that the service is available in the night (for example from "22" to "06"), I need to get results like this:

`$current_time > work_start OR $current_type < work_end`

As you can see, the only difference between queries are "AND" / "OR" conditions.

Is there an elegant solution for this or a workaround that can return the results

Comment: can you please provide sample data and the expected result?

Comment: @Jens I store service availability hours in a table, so for example if the service is available from "08" to "16", I store those values as "work_start" and "work_end". 
I need to check if the service is available currently, and query like this
where `$current_time > work_start AND $current_type < work_end`

But for the case that the service is available in the night (for example from "22" to "06", I need to get results like this:
`$current_time > work_start OR $current_type < work_end`

As you can see, the only difference between queries are "AND" / "OR" conditions.

Comment: @Jens thanks, well I'm not new to mysql but can't think of a clever solution. for being closed for whole days, there is another table where I store datetimes where the service unavailable (another story). Can't think of a solution of how to do this.

Comment: @gagvirus Please add those details to the question, not just a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IF()` or `CASE` to perform different comparisons depending on the condition.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CASE WHEN work_start < work_end
      THEN @current_time BETWEEN work_start AND work_end
      ELSE @current_time >= work_start OR @current_time <= work_end
      END
```